# how to turn a string into json keys and subkeys?

Tags: json, angular

I'm using a custom translator in Angular 2 to translate text into other languages. Right now the translator accepts a string as a key to look up the translation (using a pip) something like this:

```
let key = 'hello world'

export const LANG_EN_TRANS = {
 'hello world': 'hello world'
}

public translate(key: string): string {
  return some_translate_function[selected_language][key];
}
```

The problem is that I would like to use subkeys or multiple subkeys in my translation file, something like this:

```
let key = 'home_page.hello world'

export const LANG_EN_TRANS = {
  'home_page': {
    'hello world': 'hello world'
   },
  'some_other_page': {
    'hello world': 'hello world 2'
   },
}

public translate(key: string): string {
  return some_translate_function[selected_language][key][subkey];
}
```

So I think I need to convert the string:

```
'home_page.hello world'
```

to something like:

```
['home_page']['hello_world']
```

This might differ per string since I might want to make several sub keys.
Not sure if this is the best way to go but I would appreciate some suggestions on the best way to get this done.

Comment: You can split the string into an array with `string.split('.')` and then iterate over the array to build your object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after Rob's comment I found a working solution, thanks;

```
let key = 'home_page.hello world'

export const LANG_EN_TRANS = {
  'home_page': {
    'hello world': 'hello world'
   },
  'some_other_page': {
    'hello world': 'hello world 2'
   },
}

public translate(key: string): string {
  return translate_function[selected_language][key];
}

private translate_function(key: string): string {

  let keys: string[] = key.split('.');
  translation = som_json_file_with_translations;
  for (let key of keys){
    translation = translation[key];
  }
}
return translation;
}
```